# How to loop through all dropdown menus to check if they have a certain selected value?

Tags: jquery, dynamic-forms

I asked this question previously: [Disabling and Re-Enabling Dynamic Form Elements with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790975/disabling-and-re-enabling-dynamic-form-elements-with-jquery) but I feel that I was perhaps asking the wrong question.

Please see this fiddle for an easier way to understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/12/

I already have a function to check when the `tags` drop down is changed and what I am looking to do is to check all dropdowns of the class `dropdown` and `dropdownclone` and check if any of their selected values are `tags`.

If any of them have that value then disable the submit button by calling the function, if none of them have the `tags` value then enable the submit button for the form to be processed.

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks for any help given.

**UPDATE**

Latest fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/14/ but doesn't work... yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a selector for this an tranverse the dropdowns to check for the selected options.  Then check the length of the result to see if any were matched.

```
var selected= $('.dropdown, .dropdownclone').find('option[value=tags]:selected');

if(selected.length > 0) {
    disableSubmit();
}
else {
    enableSubmit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, the code looks good but when I added it in just above `if ($(this).val() == "agent") ` it kills the values for populating the other two dropdowns :( Perhaps I just need to place it elsewhere but not sure...

Comment: managed to get somewhere, but still experiencing some bugs - as long as the last row is set, there can be values of tag in there and the button will still be enabled. Likewise if you deleted back to having one with tags selected, the button doesn't change back to disabled... jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/59